# (re)store position and size of EACH cloned draggable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone

I have a div (canvas), that acts as a droppable for rects. Rects, that were dropped on the div, are cloned and can be dragged and resized within that div.

My questions is: How can I (re)store the position, size of the dynamically cloned elements?

How it works:
drag more than one rect onto the canvas
resize or drag it within the rect
click save

By now, it gives me the correct number of cloned rects, but it saves only the position and size of the last cloned element.

How can I add the hidden textfields for each cloned rect separately?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#rect').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: function(event, ui) {
      return $(this).clone(true);
    }

  });

  $('#bu').click(function() {
    alert("no of rect set: " + $('.rectset').length);

    $('.rectset').each(function() {
      var posTop = $('input#posTop').val();
      var posLeft = $('input#posLeft').val();
      var height = $('input#sizeHeight').val();
      var width = $('input#sizeWidth').val();

      alert("left: " + posLeft + ", top: " + posTop +
        " ,height: " + height + ", width: " + width);
    });
  });


  $("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: "#rect",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
        /*alert("rect is dragged and not copied again");*/
        return

      }

      var droppedRect = $(ui.draggable).clone().addClass('rectset')


      droppedRect.append('<input type="hidden" id="posLeft" value="empty"></input>');
      droppedRect.append('<input type="hidden" id="posTop" value="empty"></input>');
      droppedRect.append('<input type="hidden" id="sizeWidth" value="empty"></input>');
      droppedRect.append('<input type="hidden" id="sizeHeight" value="empty"></input>');

      droppedRect.appendTo(this);

      droppedRect.draggable({
        containment: "#canvas",
        scroll: false,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          // alert($('input#posLeft').val() + " " + $('input#posTop').val()) ;
          var posleft = ui.position.left;
          var postop = ui.position.top;
          $('input#posLeft').attr('value', posleft);
          $('input#posTop').attr('value', postop);
          alert($('input#posLeft').val() + " " + $('input#posTop').val());

        }
      }).resizable({
        ghost: true,
        containment: "#canvas",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $('#size').attr('value', ui.size)

          var width = ui.size.width;
          var height = ui.size.height;
          //       alert($('input#sizeWidth').val() + " " + $('input#sizeHeight').val()) ;
          $('input#sizeWidth').attr('value', width);
          $('input#sizeHeight').attr('value', height);
          alert($('input#sizeWidth').val() + " " + $('input#sizeHeight').val());

        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 150px;
}

#rect {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #ffff99;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id="bu" onclick="save()">Save</button >
<div id="rect" class="ui-widget-content"> </div> 
<div id="canvas" class="ui-widget-header">
```

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document, so that's not going to work if you have more than one. The value of a textbox should be set with `.val(value)`, not `attr`. Also, please share an [mcve] with the minimum amount of code to show your problem. **Do not keep the code on an external site**. Many people are blocked from code-sharing sites, so you're limiting the number of people who can help you. Stack Overflow has Stack Snippets which provide a very similar level of functionality to jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mike said, the IDs need to be unique.  I solved this by adding a counter `var i = 0`, then on each new `droppedRect` setting the `id` attribute to the number incremented. Also, I think a better way to achieve the same goal of putting data onto the rectangles is through [jQuery.data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).  I used jQueryUI 1.9 because that was being used in the fiddle.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#rect').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: function(event, ui) {
      return $(this).clone(true);
    }
  });
  var i = 0;
  $('#bu').click(function() {
    console.log("no of rect set: " + $('.rectset').length);

    $('.rectset').each(function(a, b) {
      console.log("left: " + $(b).data('posleft') + ", top: " + $(b).data('postop') +
        " ,height: " + $(b).data('height') + ", width: " + $(b).data('width'))
    });
  });

  $("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: "#rect",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) {
        return;
      }

      var droppedRect = $(ui.draggable).clone().addClass('rectset').attr('id', i++)
        .appendTo(this)
        .data({
          'posleft': ui.position.left,
          'postop': ui.position.top,
          'width': ui.draggable[0].offsetWidth,
          'height': ui.draggable[0].offsetHeight
        });
      console.log("Dropped - left: " + ui.position.left + " top:" + ui.position.top + " width: " + ui.draggable[0].offsetWidth + " height: " + ui.draggable[0].offsetHeight);
      droppedRect.draggable({
        containment: "#canvas",
        scroll: false,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).data('posleft', ui.position.left);
          $(this).data('postop', ui.position.top);
          console.log("Moved - left: " + ui.position.left + " top:" + ui.position.top);

        }
      }).resizable({
        ghost: true,
        containment: "#canvas",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).data('width', ui.size.width);
          $(this).data('height', ui.size.height);
          console.log("Resized - width: " + ui.size.width + " height: " + ui.size.height);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 150px;
}

.rect {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #ffff99!important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="bu">Save</button >
<div id="rect" class="rect ui-widget-content"> </div> 
<div id="canvas" class="ui-widget-header">
```